# A way to prevent moving when UI is touched?

Tags: unity-game-engine, controls

I want to move my character as I touch to a point over time. But I don't want it to target if touched point is UI element. I succeed this with mouse click for PC but not for touch on Android.

PC mouse click that works without a problem:

```
if (Input.GetMouseButton(0)) {
    if (!EventSystem.current.IsPointerOverGameObject()){
       Target = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition); 
    } 
}
```

Android touch that still moves towards UI on click:

```
if (Input.touchCount > 0){ 
    foreach (Touch touch in Input.touches){
        int id = touch.fingerId;

        if (!EventSystem.current.IsPointerOverGameObject(id))
        {
            Target = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(touch.position);
        }
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What happens if there's more than one touch and one of them isn't over an object?

Comment: @Draco18s it is moving towards between two touches. Probably it keeps moving between them but change is impossible to realise during runtime. Even if none are on UI, it works the same way.

Comment: UI issue aside, you should figure out how you want to handle that, because that's still wonky behavior. Not sure why `IsPointerOverGameObject` isn't working with the touch IDs (but I've also never used it that way).